# how to fix ''phrase' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: phrase'?

Tags: c#

whenever I start debugging this error occur on the gramList.Add(grammarFile);

> System.ArgumentException: ''phrase' cannot be an empty string.
>   Parameter name: phrase'

```
public Form1()
        {
            //initialize grammarfile
            gramList.Add(grammarFile);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(gramList));

            try
            {
                speechRecognition.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                speechRecognition.LoadGrammar(grammar);
                speechRecognition.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
                speechRecognition.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                speechRecognition.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Well, grammarFile contains an empty string and no file path. Ensure that it contains **not** an empty string. That is all

Answer (score 0):

if there are some empty lines at the end of all the text or inside the text file it must be considered an empty phrase so just remove these empty lines from the file..

open the commands file and check if there are come yellow colored lines or open commands file in notepad and check whether there are empty lines or not.